# Angular ui router dynamic routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the following library

- @version v0.2.11
- @link http://angular-ui.github.com/

What i am looking at is for dynamic routing 
for ex: for route `localhost:8080/#/about` it goes to function, let say `routedFunction`  which defines the template html `<div>about me .. </div>`

and if someone goes to `localhost:8080/#/abc` ;  `routedFunction` will get a routing url as parameter **abc** and it will know display that .. may be `<div>abc xyz abc</div>`

I am unable to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a router.

Angular documentation for `$route` can be found at @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Please find and have a look at following example in documentation. This example shows how changing the URL hash causes the $route to match a route against the URL, and the ngView pulls in the partial.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  Choose:
  <a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
  <a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
  <a href="Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
  <a href="Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: Ch4</a> |
  <a href="Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <hr />

  <pre>$location.path() = {{$location.path()}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.templateUrl = {{$route.current.templateUrl}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.params = {{$route.current.params}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.scope.name = {{$route.current.scope.name}}</pre>
  <pre>$routeParams = {{$routeParams}}</pre>
</div>
```

Here is another example for defining different routes.

```
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});
```

To learn and understand router/routing the easy way @ https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: no .. pls see the question carefully .. the routes url will not be defined in advance

Comment: You still need to use the route and pass/access dynamic information via $routeParams @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: i have stateParams in ui-router , the question is not params; the question is routing when it is not defined; there is otherwise routing in ui-router, but it changes the urll